# how to use Drupal menu system AND OR

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to display all content labeled under my taxonomy terms with ids 1 and 3. Both terms work fine so that If I point my browser to 
www.mysite/?q=taxonomy/term/1 or www.mysite/?q=taxonomy/term/3

But trying to use drupals built-in AND/OR feature using the urls below gives me a "Page not Found" error.

www.mysite/?q=taxonomy/term/1+3
www.mysite/?q=taxonomy/term/1,3

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: After more digging around I've found this. (In D7, you can no longer specify paths such as "taxonomy/term/1,2", "taxonomy/term/1+2","taxonomy/term/2/2" or "taxonomy/term/2/all". Function taxonomy_term_page (D7) does not parse the string as it did in D6.)

Comment: ...But I'd still like to know an easy way to get the same results since it was possible in version 6

Answer (score 2):

Install the [views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) and then go to `?q=admin/structure/views`.

You will find a disabled view created by default named "Taxonomy term" with an ID equal to taxonomy_term.

Enable this view; it will override the default taxonomy page. Configure the view to match your case, and click save.